# Mixture distribution and mixed distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We define **mixture distribution** as follows (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution#Finite_and_countable_mixtures)):
Given a finite set of probability density functions $p_1(x), \ldots, p_n(x)$, or corresponding cumulative distribution functions $P_1(x), \ldots, P_n(x)$ and weights $w_1, \ldots, w_n$ such that $w_i \ge 0$ and $\sum w_i = 1$, the mixture distribution can be represented by writing either the density, $f$,  or the distribution function, $F$, as a sum (which in both cases is a convex combination):
$\displaystyle F(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \, w_i \, P_i(x),$
$\displaystyle f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \, w_i \, p_i(x).$

Next, **mixed distribution** is defined as follows (see [here](http://www.randomservices.org/random/dist/Mixed.html) or [here](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter4/4_3_1_mixed.php)):
Let $X$ be a random variable taking values in $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Then $X$ has a distribution of mixed type if $S$ can be partitioned into subsets $D$ and $C$ with the following properties:
a) $D$ is countable and $0 \lt P(X \in D) \lt 1$.
b) $P(X = x) = 0$ for all $x \in C$.

**Question.**
Is it true that mixture distribution with at least one discrete term ($P_i(x)$) and at least one continuous term ($P_j(x)$) in its CDF is equivalent to mixed distribution? I.e. mixed distribution is just a special case of a mixture distribution?

(*I think yes, particularly for $n=2$ we have $w_1 = P(X \in D), w_2 = 1 - w_1$ if $P_1$(x) is discrete and $P_2(x)$ is continuous. But I'm not completely sure...*)

Comment: Good question.  What is the context in which you've come across this?

Comment: @phdmba7of12 I studied probability and saw that in several sources there was definition of mixture distribution while in other sources there was definition of mixed distribution. But I didn't see any sources (among textbooks and websites) which contained both definitions at once. So I asked the question about this.